# Import multiple csv files into a list and skip files which don't exist

Tags: r, file, lapply, skip, read.csv

I need to import diverse `csv` files from a source into a list by using `lapply`.

The point is that the csv files that I want are e.g. 100 but the source contains only 80 of them.

How can I skip the files that are not included in the source?

Here my code:

```
stations <- read.csv("stations.csv", header = TRUE)
filenames <- paste(stations$ID, "csv", sep = ".") #define the filenames
directory <- "~I/am/not/that/dumb" #set directory where take files to read
filenames <- file.path(directory, filenames) #construct the files paths

list <- lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) #import the csv into a list
```

But I got the error:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition:
>   Warning message: In file(file, "rt") :   cannot open file
>   '/Users/I/am/not/that/dumb/26003.csv': No such file or directory

obviously because the file 26003.csv is not contained into the source.

**Any suggestion on how to skip the non-existent files?**

The csv files to import in total are >> 100 therefore I can't do it manually.

Comment: Perhaps use the results of `dir(directory)` or the intersection of this with filenames: `myFilenames <- intersect(dir(directory), filenames))` should return a vector of the filenames in your initial csv that are actually in the directory.

Comment: You can't `Filter` out the files that don't exist with `file.exists`?

Comment: guys thanks a lot but I am asking you :)

Comment: `lapply(Filter(file.exists, filenames), read.csv, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`?

Comment: @Imo thanks a lot. your suggestion works fine. If you want to post your answer I will accept it as correct.

Comment: The answer below covers both my suggested method and a nice alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two options.

**1)** Check for existence of file names before importing (similar to a comment on the OP):

```
stations <- read.csv("stations.csv", header = TRUE)
filenames <- paste(stations$ID, "csv", sep = ".") 
directory <- "~I/am/not/that/dumb" 
filenames <- file.path(directory, filenames)
filenames <- intersect(filenames, list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)) # added
list <- lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**2)** Use `try` / `tryCatch` to handle errors:

A simple approach would be:

```
stations <- read.csv("stations.csv", header = TRUE)
filenames <- paste(stations$ID, "csv", sep = ".") 
directory <- "~I/am/not/that/dumb" 
filenames <- file.path(directory, filenames) 

lst <- lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  try(read.csv(x, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
})
```

The resulting list-object may then contain `try-error` elements. If you want to remove them, you can use

```
lst <- lst[sapply(lst, function(x) !inherits(x, "try-error"))]
```